# View of CiviCRM Events containing CiviCRM Contact Data

Tags: drupal-views, civicrm-entity

I need to set up a list of Upcoming Events in Drupal 7 with a **View of CiviCRM Events** Entity.

I need to redirect the logged user to a Drupal Custom Node after the user has selected a specific event to sign in, through a Link containing in the ULR his/her **CiviCRM Contact ID**.

Does anyone have an idea how I can achieve that? I haven't worked with Hooks for the moment, so would it be possible to get that feature without developing custom code?

Another posibility could be to pre-populate the **Existing Contact Field** in the **Webform** with the logged CiviCRM Contact, but I can´t find any other way to do that, just through the parameter **cid** (contact id) **from the URL**.

Thanks in advance.